# Find picklist values in Dynamics via the Web API

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, metadata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to determine how I can find the integer values for picklist fields in Dynamics via the web api.  I can access the basic metadata by using:

```
GET https://[COMPANY].api.crm3.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0//EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='lead')/Attributes/
```

but for picklist values I don't see the mapping of the integer value to the displayed string.

Is there a table that holds all of this or a way to expand this information on the above call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this to retrieve.

```
https://[COMPANY].api.crm3.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='{Entity Name}')/Attributes(LogicalName='{OptionSet Name}')/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=GlobalOptionSet($select=Options)
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-metadata-web-api#querying-entitymetadata-attributes)

Comment: Hello Arun, what is that `($select=option)` in the end?

Comment: @Hemang that will give the options in the select list